# MySQL match keywords where order doesn't matter

Tags: php, mysql

I want to match a string of keywords separated by commas with another string of keywords separated by commas in the database where the order of the keywords doesn't matter.

## Examples

`keywords,separated,by,commas` **WOULD MATCH:**

- `separated,keywords,commas,by` (**where all of the keywords in the list match and are present**)
- `separated,keywords,commas,by,keywords` (**repeated keywords**)

And **NOT MATCH:**

- `separated,keywords,commas` (**less keywords**)
- `keywords,separated,by,commas,extra` (**more non-repeating keyword(s)**)

## Example Usage

For example, I have a string of keywords (`keywords,separated,by,commas`).  I want to check if the database has a column the `keywords` index is equal to that list regardless of the order.

I would want to be able to check it similiarly to this:

```
$keywords = "keywords,seperated,by,commas";
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE keywords = ".$keywords;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($results) echo "Keywords found in database";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a select for each term.

Try this:

```
$keywords = "keywords,seperated,by,commas";
$words = explode(',', $keywords);
$where = '';
foreach($words as $word) {
    $where .= " keywords like '%$word%' and ";
}
$where = rtrim($where, ' and ');
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE " . $where;
echo $query;
```

which should give you a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM search WHERE  keywords like 'keywords' and  keywords like 'seperated' and  keywords like 'by' and  keywords like 'commas'
```

This will only return rows that contain all of the keywords, regardless of the order.

Comment: This didn't exactly word for me so I changed `$where .= " keywords like '$word' and ";` to `$where .= " keywords like '%$word%' and ";`, which works fine except when you have less keywords in $keyword that match one in the database with more keywords that aren't included in the $keyword variable.

Comment: Oh yea, without `%`s it is the whole column opps. Can you describe the other issue more, or provide an example?

Comment: If you look for the keywords `separated,commas` it will return all columns that have the keywords `separted` and `commas` not the column that has just `separated,commas`, no other keywords.

Comment: There's more than one `keywords` column? It should be returning all rows that have all the keywords, partial keywords shouldn't be returned. Maybe making a SQLfiddle demonstrating issue would be easiest.. http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: No, there are multiple keywords in the keywords column though.

Comment: Oh, so you want exact match no other keywords. So if searching for `a` and `b` but a row had `a`, `b`, and `c` it shouldnt be found; but rows `b`, `a` and `a`, `b` should be found. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly!  Should I still make a sqlfidde?

Comment: The `like` approach won't work in this case.  You'll need to check for an exact match with all permutations of the keywords. I would think about restructuring the table. If you make up a SQLfiddle I might be able to draft you up a different table structure if that approach would be possible.

Comment: I've changed the structure so drastically that nothing has been said here applies.

Comment: Is it working for you know or can you update the question/or sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I have check your MySQL query. I think you have to use  IN in your query to search keyword.

Here is updated query.

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE keywords IN ( ".$keywords.")";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
     $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     if ($results) echo "Keywords found in database";
```

This may help you.